# WOMOIWIW: What Org-mode Opens is What I Want

Tags: beginner, lisp, elisp

## Motivation

Previously, on the [Emacs stack exchange](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/61246/20061):

> In Org mode, when I open a link (<kbd>C-c C-o</kbd>) [...] [that] contains a wildcard, such as `file:3_o*.pdf`, Emacs opens it through `dired` instead [...] within Emacs.
>
> I would instead have it open the first match of that pattern in the system application …

The handling of `file:` links is hard-coded in Org mode. If there is any wildcard in the given `path`, then `org-link-open` will nope out of the situation and instead call `dired`. And while one could change Org mode's source code in the local elisp files, I remembered that you can change the arguments or results of functions with [advices](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html).

## Solution

I opted for an advice `:around` `org-link-open` with the following code:

```lisp
(defun my-org-expand-file-link (link)
  "Expand a pattern in LINK to the first matching file.

Returns the original LINK if no file matches the pattern in LINK or if it is not
a link of type 'file:'.  See info node `(org)External links' for more information."
  (let ((type (org-element-property :type link))
        (path (org-element-property :path link)))
    (cond
     ((equal type "file")
      (let ((candidates (file-expand-wildcards path)))
        (if candidates
            (org-element-put-property (org-element-copy link) :path (car candidates))
          link)))
     (t link))))

(defun my-org-link-open-advice (orig-fun link &rest args)
  "Advice for ORIG-FUN that expands patterns in 'file:' LINKs.
See `my-org-expand-file-link' for more information.
Optional argument ARGS are passed as-is."
  (apply orig-fun (my-org-expand-file-link link) args))

(advice-add 'org-link-open :around #'my-org-link-open-advice)
```

So whenever you open a link with <kbd>C-c C-o</kbd> (`org-open-at-point` which calls `org-link-open`), you end up with a concrete file.

[image: link expansion]

## Some remarks

I recommend using a custom link type like `first:` or wrapping the code above minor mode, as the advice is somewhat invasive and might surprise users that *really* want to get a list of matching files instead.

I'm open to any feedback on the elisp code, especially since I'm still a elisp newbie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a cool feature I've to say.  And the code looks excellent, I
suppose you could argue for one or the other wrt. `cond` vs. `if`
etc. but that's pointless pedantry IMO.

Given that it works flawlessly (tried locally and via tramp as well), I
was unsure there was actually anything to say here, but I found two
points that might be of interest:

Firstly, while the `:around` combinator works fine, it might be more
appropriate to use `:filter-args`, since it's really just filtering the
arguments:

```
(defun my-org-link-open-advice (args)
  "Advice for ORIG-FUN that expands patterns in 'file:' LINKs.
See `my-org-expand-file-link' for more information.
Optional argument ARGS are passed as-is."
  (list* (my-org-expand-file-link (first args)) (rest args)))

(advice-add 'org-link-open :filter-args #'my-org-link-open-advice)
```

The functionality is absolutely unchanged of course.

Secondly, and this is conflicting with the previous point, I could
imagine using the prefix argument (so <kbd>C-u C-c C-o</kbd>) to
distinguish the two cases of whether to run the original behaviour, or
not, like so:

```
(defun my-org-link-open-advice (orig-fun link &optional arg &rest args)
  "Advice for ORIG-FUN that expands patterns in 'file:' LINKs.
See `my-org-expand-file-link' for more information.
Optional argument ARGS are passed as-is."
  (apply orig-fun (if arg link (my-org-expand-file-link link)) arg args))
```

To quote the function docstring for `org-link-open`:

> ARG is an optional prefix argument.  Some link types may handle it.
> For example, it determines what application to run when opening a
> "file" link.

This might interfere with the above idea, however practically I couldn't see a
difference with the unadvised function and this argument being present
or not, YMMV.

Comment: Thanks for the review. TIL about the aliases `first` and `rest` for `car` and `cdr`!

Comment: Right, I actually thought for teaching purposes to use `first` and `rest`, normally I go for the shorter ones :)